# Restore mongodb database from blockstore snapshot backup

Tags: mongodb, restore, snapshot, ops-manager

I have a situation where I need to restore the mongodb database from the blockstore snapshot backup taken from the ops manager which is used to manage 3 node replica set. I need to restore this backup into the new completly  standalone instance in the DR site. 
I am new working with MongoDB and not sure where to start. 
I tried to do some research but could not find an exact solution. 
Any suggestions please ?

Comment: you're saying that you could not find any solution as [how to store a mongodb backup from a blockstore snapshot](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/nav/backup-restore-deployments/)?

Comment: [here](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/restore-pit-snapshot-http/index.html) you can find a picture of the architecture